# Magento 2 : Adding static blocks to specific section of pages with custom module layout xml file

Tags: layout, magento2, cms-block

In magento 1.x it is possible to add a static block using xml layout file.

```
<reference name="root">
        <block type="cms/block" name="name">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>static-block-id</block_id></action>
        </block>
</reference>
```

But, in magento 2 how we can achieve it ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. You can call static block using following way.

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>

     <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">promo</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: How did you find out the reference name?

Comment: @StevieG Either [locate it](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html) or read the default XML implementations so you know how everything is built up (very useful to do for long term).

Answer (score 8):

It can be done easily from the admin panel by following the steps below.

1. Go to Content -> Widgets
2. Add New Widget
3. Select type as CMS Static Block
4. Select Design Package/Theme And Continue
5. Set `Widget Title`, `Store` and `Sort order` in `Storefront properties` tab
6. Select static block from in the `Widget options` tab
7. Save the widget
8. Click On `Add Layout Update` button
9. Select Option from `Display on` dropdown e.g. : `Specific page` to display block on specifi
10. Select Page from the `Page` dropdown
11. Select Container from `Container` dropdown
12. save the widget

Comment: It is useful to CMS pages only. Can we use it in our custom module xml too?

Comment: I have provided the cms page example only, you can use it for every possible module or page. you can get an idea by seeing the list of the option in the Display on dropdown

Comment: This is excellent, clean and simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to call static-block in 2columns-left page, you can simply do it using,

here below you can change `quickblock` with your static-block identifier.

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="quick-block">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">quickblock</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Above Block is working fine for 2columns-left with sidebar.

Comment: Hi  If we want to call the static block only for category page layout then?

i did call static block in xml with sidebar.additional but it's not working.  What could be the reason?

Comment: @Rakesh, <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('identiefier_id')->toHtml(); 
?> I used in success.phtml , its not working

Answer (score 2):

In the following code, change the "block_identifier" from the CMS block created on magento dashboard and add it to layout.xml. It works.

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
       <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_identifier</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```